# Pythonic way to handle a method on network data structure

Tags: algorithm, python, duck-typing, typechecking

So, another question on what is Pythonic!  The application domain in this case is network algorithms (as in, nodes, edges, Dijkstra, that kind of thing...), something I have only previously coded in strongly typed languages where we can be very certain what everything *is*.

Meanwhile in Python, I've got a class `Net`; a single instance of this class represents a network.  I have a class `Edge` which is instantiated for each edge in the network.  Each `Edge` instance has, among other things, a unique `id`.

Sometimes I wish to remove an edge by reference to the relevant `Edge` instance.  Other times I wish to remove an Edge using its `id`.  To be honest, I'm starting to lose track of which variables are `Edges` and which are `ids`.  I think I preferred C++ for this job :-P

So I propose two solutions:

1. Start using systems Hungarian notation - name my variables better so I know whether they are actual Edge objects or just the id of the Edge I want.  Implement strong typing - make `remove_edge` (which is a method on `Net`) explicitly reject anything that isn't an `Edge`.  Make a wrapper function `remove_edge_id` which looks up the relevant `Edge` from its `id` and then calls `remove_edge`; this function likewise rejects anything that isn't an `id`.
2. Use duck typing.  Have `remove_edge` check whether the argument is an `id` or an `Edge` and just do the right thing with it.

Whadday'all reckon?

Comment: It might be worth stepping back and asking why you're finding yourself using both object references and IDs to track edges. Is it holdover from C++ habits? Is it possible to modify other stuff to always use one or the other?

Comment: What you're referring to is called a 'graph', not a 'network'.

Comment: Fair point.  I have been blinded by the terminology of my application domain ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The duck-typing solution is by far more Pythonic. However, rather than testing the argument to see whether it's an ID or an edge, just treat it as if it were the more common case first, and if that doesn't work, try it the other way.

If you do use explicit type-checking, which is sometimes the only way, use `isintance()` rather than `type()` so it'll work with subclasses.

A variable can be well-named or poorly-named, which is orthogonal to whether you are using strong typing or not. If you have some variables that reference an Edge ID, and others that reference an Edge instance, distinguishing them in some way seems smart even if you're using duck typing. I'd use something like `edge` and `edge_id` rather than Hungarian though.

Comment: Sounds sensible, I think this might be definitive but leaving the question open for a while to encourage discussion

Answer (score 2):

I would say a mix of both.

It's good practice to have names of objects that you can tell what they are or what they might do from looking at them (for the most part). I would name my edges `edge` and my edge ids `edge_id`.

I would probably use your duck typing idea for `remove_edge`.

```
def remove_edge(edge):
    if isinstance(edge, int):
        edge = get_edge_from_id(edge)
    #delete edge here!!
```

Comment: Is it just me, or will that cause a stack overflow? :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to remove your edge by id , you can simply do something like this :

```
class Net:
   def remove_edge(self, edge):
      try:
         self.remove_edge_by_id(edge.id)
      except AttributeError:     # oups, edge was not an Edge, it has no id
         self.remove_edge_by_id(edge)   # it should be an id
```

Comment: +1 for code illustration of how to treat the most common case first as @kindall suggested.  Makes it a bit clearer!